# What has historically been the effect of a long rain delay on a pitcher's arm?

Tags: baseball

By "long" delay, I mean an hour or more.

On one hand, a pitcher that has pitched two or three innings, and is interrupted by rain gets a chance to rest.

On the other hand, perhaps a pitcher has warmed up, and gotten into a "rhythm." Then perhaps the delay "undid" all this work.

Has a pitcher been likely to pitch the same way after a rain delay as before? Suppose there is more than one rain delay in the game. Has it been  disruptive to most pitchers?

I was think in terms of last night's game, San Diego vs. Pittsburgh. Why did San Diego relieve its starter after two innings and an almost two hour rain delay, when he had given up no runs?

Comment: A very subjective question, it all comes down to how focused the pitcher can remain. To make a comeback with same efficiency, he must be 1. Warmed up thoroughly and 2. Remain focused.

Comment: @Invoker: I made the question not subjective by asking what has happened historically. That question can be answered objectively.

Comment: I don't have historical data to answer, but pitchers warm up before a game by throwing 50-100 pitches.  If the pitcher takes a long period of time off his arm will tighten up.  Many pitchers say that a few hours after a start they cant lift their arm.  I am sure that pitchers could throw during a delay to stay lose, but if they throw too much then it would have the effect of throwing a long game.  It is a risk situation.  Do you want o jeopardize 20 more starts for 4 more innings...?

Comment: It's quite common to replace the pitcher - I suspect mostly to avoid injury from pitching after his muscles have cooled.